# SqlDataReader inside SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatareader

How can I implement a `SqlDataReader` inside another `SqlDataReader`?

My problem is I have a `SqlDataReader`. I am issuing `while (reader.read())` and inside the while loop I have to create another `SqlDataReader` to read from the database. But I'm getting exceptions about connection being already open.

So what's the best way to solve my problem?

Edit:

I am using clr to create my stored procedures. I tried to put `MultipleActiveResultSets=true;` within the connection string of both the clr and the project, and an exception occurred when I 
tested my stored procedure on SQL Server:

> System.InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

Comment: Are you using the same connection with the previous SqlDataReader? Have you tried creating a new one?

Comment: yes sure. i tried to create a new one, the thing is that i am using clr, it works when i deploy but when i use the stored procedure in my application an excepion occurs...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to have two nested data readers, and this requires the ADO.NET "MARS" feature - Multiple Active Result Sets.

This is available as of ADO.NET 2.0, and requires a specific setting (**`MultipleActiveResultSets=true;`**) in the connection string:

```
Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;
  MultipleActiveResultSets=true;
```

See this [blog post](http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/kaushalparik/archive/2008/06/19/multiple-active-result-sets-mars-ado-net-2-0.aspx) for an excellent discussion.

Once you have this, you should be able to have more than one `SqlDataReader` shared on the same `SqlConnection` in your code, and use them independently of one another.

**UPDATE:** this [blog post here](http://weblogs.asp.net/aaguiar/archive/2004/05/26/141963.aspx) mentions that the MARS feature is not available inside the SQL CLR environment :-( So that won't work inside a SQL CLR stored proc....

Comment: yes, it definitely should (as long as they're using the same connection, e.g. an **identical** connection string - identical down to the last comma and whitespace!)

Comment: well it did not work when using clr. after i created my stored procedure, i tried to test it on MS-SQL and an exepction occured which stated that:

System.InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

Comment: @scatman: yes, unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be be supported - see my update..... sorry

Answer (score 6):

The issue you're encountering is that you are trying to open multiple data readers against the same db connection. By default, this will give you an exception as it will say there's already one associated with the connection - as you've seen.

You could make use of [MultipleActiveResultsets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf(VS.80).aspx), whereby from .NET 2.0 & SQL Server 2005 onwards, you can specify an extra option in the connection string to enable multiple active resultsets against a single db connection by adding:

```
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
```

The alternative is to use a different connection to open the inner data reader against.

Or even, it may be possible to rethink your original approach - maybe there's a way to do it without nested readers.